Does Hyperledger Fabric Samples v2.5.9 support BFT?
I am working with hyperledger fabric samples v2.5.9 and want to be able to use BFT. The only solution I've found is to use the BETA v3.0.0 of fabric. I would like to avoid this and there seems to be a way to do this within v2.5.9, but I can't seem to figure out how to configure it properly.
Just trying to run the network with BFT doesn't work and the -h command details that -bft isn't supported in versions v2.x. Whenever I find related documentation in the hyperledger fabric docs, it will reference v3.0 and I don't know that that documentation will be effective on v2.5.9. I was able to run ./network.sh up -bft but not ./network.sh createChannel -bft as it said: Failed to generate channel configuration transaction...

A Byzantine Fault Tolerant (BFT) ordering service is only available in Hyperledger Fabric v3. It is the main new feature in that release.
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/whatsnew.html
Prior to a full v3 release, using a v3 beta release (or a more recent development build) is your only option to use BFT consensus with Fabric.
